# CustomUser relation doesn't exist : Django migration error

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-custom-user

I'm quite new to Django and ran into a problem while trying to create a custom user.
I followed all the steps outlined to create one, but because I initially started out with the default User model I deleted all my migrations and my postgres db to start from scratch (if not, I read it would cause problems).

makemigrations works fine, but then when I want to migrate I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "cyclabApp_customuser" does not exist.

Applying admin.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "cyclabApp_customuser" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 229, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 115, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

My docker container also outputs the following:

```
2021-04-12 10:22:13.665 UTC [95] STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE "django_admin_log" ADD CONSTRAINT "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_cyclabApp_customuser_id" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "cyclabApp_customuser" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

I've looked everywhere for similar problems and their solutions, but no luck so far in trying to fix this issue...

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Is the app where the custom user model is defined not in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings?

Comment: It is in the settings... like so, INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'cyclabApp.apps.CyclabappConfig',

Comment: Did you by any chance delete the entire migrations folder of your app? Try running `python manage.py makemigrations cyclabApp`.

Comment: Hm, I don't think I ever deleted the entire folder. I tried to run the makemigrations that way, but the migration still gives me the same error after that...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it.
Apparently I was missing the model for my UserManager. Worked after I added that. :-)

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(
            self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None,
            commit=True):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, first name, last name
        and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have an email address'))
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have a first name'))
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have a last name'))

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        if commit:
            user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```